# slope, intercept, ggplot2, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted a time series data on `ggplot` with Year on the x axis and rain on the y axis.
I would like to overlay a trend line on this plot ( my equation for this trend line is `rain = 2.6*Year + 23`). My slope was computed using the theil sen method
How can I overlay this on my plot

My code thus far is

```
ggplot(data = Datarain, aes(x = year, y = rain)) + 
  geom_smooth(color="red", formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE color="blue", formula = y ~ x) +   
  geom_line() + scale_x_continuous("Year")
```

I am not sure how to add my own equation on my plot or how to add a thiel sen line in `ggplot`

Any ideas would be grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `geom_abline` to specify your linear equation

```
ggplot(data = Datarain, aes(x = year, y = rain)) + 
  geom_smooth(color="red", formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE color="blue", formula = y ~ x) +   
  geom_line() + scale_x_continuous("Year") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 23, slope = 2.6)
```

Comment: thank you very much. just realized that it did not intercept at the value where i wanted to ...i think it just drew the lm line

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working..then i tried this alone p <- qplot(year, R10, data = RR10mm) + geom_abline(19.2, slope = 0.124).. but then i realized that geom_abline is not drawing the line on the scatterplot .. do you think something maybe wrong with my package

Comment: @nee could you post a small sample of the data?